# Way to use my SQL result as filter condition?

Tags: php, sql, header, conditional-statements

I have a database table with user id, name and their role_id. So I try to use their role_id to limit the user.

What in my thought is putting the `$result` into the condition and then give them the header they 'suppose' to have according to their role when they log in.

Is this possible in the first place, cause the page is like it ignore my condition.

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");

    exit;
}

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','mes');
$sql = "SELECT role_id from users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] == true && $result === '202000' ){
    include_once "premierHeader.php";

else{
      include_once "header.php";
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in your syntax : 
your else is between the braces of the if condition

then try to use brackets in your condition, for example like this
if( (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] == true) && ($result === '202000') )